# Rails 5.1, delete multiple records with conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, conditional-statements, record, destroy

I try to delete several records in my DB according to a few conditions. Before I talk about my problem I will explain how my app is working.

A User can create groups and links. This User own the groups he created same for the links. Other Users can then join this group by providing a token (which is created automatically when the group is created) via a Member model. Where member has the user_id and the group_id in the DB. Then once the User is part of a group he can share the links he created in the groups via Grouplink model. Where grouplink has groupd_id and link_id.

I managed to code the fact that if there is no member in a group the group is destroyed. But how do I manage to remove the links a user shared in the group if he leaves the group ? (when the user is destroyed automatically all the links are deleted so I think that the sharing should be gone as well, I have to try that tho'). When a User leaves the group I destroy his member record and he is gone but the links remain. I display the shared links, the fact that you can kick users (member destroy) and the list of the members of a group in the group show btw.

I thought about a few things. I write down what I did in the console

```
g = Group.find(66)
u = g.users.find(1)
u.links
```

and that give me all the links from the user in the group. Next to that

```
g.grouplinks
```

would give me all the shared links in the group.

```
g.grouplinks.map(&:link_id) returns [16, 17, 14, 13, 15]
u.links.map(&:id) returns [13, 15]
```

Now what can I do here ? My user is leaving the group. The member record is destroyed and how can I destroy those grouplinks according to the links the users has ?
Is there a magic trick I don't know yet ?

Thanks for your help.

EDIT

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

    has_secure_password


  has_many :links, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :grouplinks, dependent: :destroy

  has_many :members, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :groups, :through => :members
  has_one :owned_group, foreign_key: "owner_id", class_name: "Group"
end

class Member < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :group

  validates :user_id, :presence => true
  validates :group_id, :presence => true
  validates :user_id, :uniqueness => {:scope => [:user_id, :group_id]}

end

class Link < ApplicationRecord

    has_many :grouplinks, :dependent => :destroy
    belongs_to :user

end

class Grouplink < ApplicationRecord

    belongs_to :group
    belongs_to :link

end

class Group < ApplicationRecord
has_secure_token :auth_token

    has_many :members, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :users, through: :members, source: :user
    belongs_to :owner, class_name: "User"

    has_many :links, through: :grouplinks
    has_many :grouplinks, :dependent => :destroy

    def to_param
        auth_token
    end

end
```

I thought that actually I could add the user_id in the grouplinks so I could delete_all according to the user_id in the links and in the groupslinks. Not sure how to that tho' and don't know if there is a better solution.

EDIT 2

I tried your solution within the models. Actually it is smart and I didn't think about that...
Problem is now with the creation of my grouplink (share the link). I had this :

```
  def create
    user = current_user if current_user
    group = user.groups.find_by(auth_token: params[:auth_token])
    share = group.id
    group_link = group.grouplinks.build(link_id: params[:link_id])
    gl = group.grouplinks
    if gl.where(group_id: share).where(link_id: params[:link_id]).exists?
        flash[:error] = "You shared this link in '#{group.name}' already."
        redirect_to mylinks_path
    else
        if group_link.save
          group_link.toggle!(:shared)
          flash[:success] = "You shared your link in '#{group.name}'."
          redirect_to mylinks_path
        else
          render 'new'
        end
    end
  end
```

And this is obviously not working anymore and I have this error when I try to share a link : `First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty` `<%= form_for @grouplink do |f| %>`.

I tried to change it like this :

```
def create
    group = Group.find_by(auth_token: params[:auth_token])
    share = group.id
    group_link = group.grouplinks.build(link_id: params[:link_id])
    gl = group.grouplinks
    if gl.where(group_id: share).where(link_id: params[:link_id]).exists?
        flash[:error] = "You shared this link in '#{group.name}' already."
        redirect_to mylinks_path
    else
        if group_link.save
          group_link.toggle!(:shared)
          flash[:success] = "You shared your link in '#{group.name}'."
          redirect_to mylinks_path
        else
          render 'new'
        end
    end
  end
```

But it is not working either

Comment: Can you show your relevant models?

Comment: Done Pablo, I updated the main topic, let me know if you need something else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
class Member < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :group
  has_many :group_links, dependent: :destroy

  validates :user_id, :presence => true
  validates :group_id, :presence => true
  validates :user_id, :uniqueness => {:scope => [:user_id, :group_id]}

end
```

and

```
class Grouplink < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :link
  belongs_to :member

end
```

Now, when a `Member` record is destroyed (i.e., the `user` is kicked out of or leaves the `group`), any `links` shared with the `group` (i.e., `group_links`) are also destroyed. But, if the `user` has shared the `link` in another `group`, the `link` will continue to be shared with the other `groups`.

As mentioned by @Pablo in the comments, you probably also want to do:

```
class Group < ApplicationRecord
  has_secure_token :auth_token

  has_many :members, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :grouplinks, through: :members
  has_many :users, through: :members, source: :user
  belongs_to :owner, class_name: "User"

  has_many :links, through: :grouplinks

  def to_param
      auth_token
  end

end
```

Which will allow you to do:

```
group.grouplinks
```

I also agree with @amr-el-bakry that `Member` is a bit confusing. I suggest `GroupUser` as it makes it quite clear that it is an association between `Group` and `User`.

Also, I think it might be a bit more conventional to say `GroupLink` instead of `Grouplink`. Or, if you want to stick with naming based on associated classes, perhaps `MemberLink`. If you change `Member` to `GroupUser`, then perhaps `GroupUserLink`.

I'm thinking your `create` code should probably look something like:

```
  def create
    if group
      if member
        if link
          unless group_link
            @group_link = member.group_links.build(link: link)
            if group_link.save
              group_link.toggle!(:shared)
              flash[:success] = "You shared your link in '#{group.name}'."
              redirect_to mylinks_path
            else
              render :new
            end
          else
            flash[:error] = "You shared this link in '#{group.name}' already."
        else
          flash[:error] = "That link does not exist."
          redirect_to somewhere #fix this
        end
      else
        flash[:error] = "You must be a member of this group to add a link."
        redirect_to somewhere #fix this
      end
    else
      flash[:error] = "There is no group with that token."
      redirect_to somewhere #fix this
    end
  end

private

  def group
    @group ||= Group.find_by(auth_token: params[:auth_token])
  end

  def member 
    @member ||= current_user.members.where(group: group)
  end

  def link
    @link ||= Link.find_by(id: params[:link_id])
  end

  def group_link
    @group_link ||= member.group_links.where(link: link)
  end
```

You *may* be able to write this as:

```
  def create

    flash[:error] = "There is no group with that token."
    redirect_to somewhere unless group

    flash[:error] = "You must be a member of this group to add a link."
    redirect_to somewhere unless member

    flash[:error] = "That link does not exist."
    redirect_to somewhere unless link

    flash[:error] = "You shared this link in '#{group.name}' already."
    redirect_to mylinks_path if group_link

    flash[:error] = nil

    @group_link = member.group_links.build(link: link)
    if group_link.save
      group_link.toggle!(:shared)
      flash[:success] = "You shared your link in '#{group.name}'."
      redirect_to mylinks_path
    else
      render :new
    end

  end
```

But I can't remember if those redirects will give you heartache.

Comment: I posted a similar answer at the same time :). I think you don’t need the belongs_to group in the group_link as it belongs to a member, that belongs to a group.

Comment: Formally, I believe you are correct. Although, it allows you to do `group.grouplinks` instead of `Grouplink.where(member: group.members)`.

Comment: Wouldn´t group has_many :members, group has_many :grouplinks through :members and member has_many :group_links allow group.grouplinks?

Comment: You are correct. And I am moving too fast. I will add to answer as I think it is an important add. Very nice!

Comment: I edited the first topic again I have a new error after those changes. It makes sense, didn't think about that.

Comment: I edited my answer to address this new issue. Sorry for the mess, but I don’t want to edit this answer as it is not mine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer I have this as a issue now `undefined method `grouplinks' for #<Member::ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation:0xa53c3c0> Did you mean? group!` `@grouplink ||= member.grouplinks.where(link: link)`. I don't have the time to check that out anymore for today. I will have a look on all that tomorrow, thanks a lot guys for your answers

Comment: Sorry, should be: `@member ||= current_user.members.where(group: group).first` and `@group_link ||= member.group_links.where(link: link).first`. `where` returns a `relation` and you want a `record`.

Comment: Very nice ! Works perfectly. Since I made a few changes with this relation I'm a little bit confused but I think I will sort this out. Spend a little bit of time in the console and should be ok. Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is `dependent :delete_all`

In your `Group` Model, you want to you should have a line like:

```
has_many :links, dependent :delete_all
```

This says, the group has many links and if you destroy the group, destroy all the related links.

Comment: The OP isn't trying to destroy all `links` associated with a `group`. Rather, the `links` that a `member` has shared with a `group`.

Answer (score 1):

In your `Member` model, you could use an `after_destroy` callback to destroy all user links in the group after membership record is destroyed:

```
class Member < ApplicationRecord
  after_destroy do |record|
    record.user.links.each { |link| link.grouplinks.where(group_id: record.group.id).destroy_all }
  end

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :group

  ...

end
```

Also, I suggest you change `Member` to `Membership` to be more clear.

Comment: This will destroy all `grouplinks` for the `user` associated with the `member` record. If the `user` is a `member` in another `group` and has shared `links` with that other `group`, those `grouplinks` will be destroyed, too.

Comment: @jvillian yes, you're absolutely right. I forgot to add the where condition. Anyway, your solution is actually a better approach to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best idea is that the group_links belong to a member and a link  (and not a group and a link). And a member (not a user) has many group_links. When your destroy the member, it will destroy the group_links.

**EDIT**

This is what jvillian suggested in his answer, just before I did. So I believe his answer is the right one (with some minor enhancements I suggested in comments that jvillian will surely accept and add :-).

**EDIT2**

Regarding the problem you faced after applying jvillian suggestion, when creating a new grouplink, it must be done from a member (not a group). So in the create action you must search the member (by user_id and group_id) and create the grouplink as member.grouplinks.build

Comment: Added with attribution. BTW, it seems to me `source: :user` may also be extraneous in the `Group` `has_many :users` association. No? Also, `group.links` will need some work - but I've already spent too much time on this one. Maybe you have a clever, easy answer for that bit.